# VNC and VPN working together problem

Tags: windows-7, vpn, vnc

Here is the situation.  I connect via VNC to a computer running UltraVNC server.  Then, I connect to a VPN on the UltraVNC server computer that I 've just connected to.  Once the VPN connection is established, the VNC connection to the UltraVNC server is lost, thus ending my VNC session.  How can I connect to a VPN from the UltraVNC server computer and not kill the VNC session?  All computer are running Windows 7.

Comment: A VPN connection generally forces all network traffic through the VPN. By connecting to a computer and then initiating a VPN at that computer, you're interrupting your initial connection. Is there any reason you cannot initiate the VPN connection from the initial host?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to untick the **Use default gateway on remote network** option on the VPN connection.

1. Edit the VPN connection properties.
2. Click on the **Networking** tab.
3. Click on **Internet Protocol Version 4**.

   1. *You may also need to disable Internet Protocol Version 6*
4. Click the **Advanced** button.
5. Untick the **Use default gateway on remote network** option.
6. Press **OK** to apply the new settings.

[image: Advanced TCP/IP Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide much detail around the Virtual Server you are trying to connect to, but I guess you connect via RDP from a *client PC Machine M* to a *server S* located on a *network N* and while connected to M, you setup a *VPN connection to Network V*. Is that correct?

If yes, the most likely reason why your connection to *Server S* drops is because your VPN client was configured to prevent [Split Tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).

Under this sort of configuration the VPN client modifies the normal IP routes so that **all traffic leaving the client PC must flow through the VPN tunnel** (excluding of course the traffic required to establish the VPN tunnel itself).

As consequence, the session between *Machine M* and *Server S* is not routed via the tunnel to *VPN Network V* and from there redirected to *Server S* on *Network N*.

This will generally cause many issues due to one of the following:

- The traffic routed to the VPN tunnel will suffer NAT before reaching to Network N and as consequence *Server S* will reject packets as Sequence numbers and other TCP session values on *Machine M* don't match those on *Server S*;
- The router on *Network V* doen't know or intentionally block the traffic to *Network N* the connection will simply be dropped.

**The good news is:** This behaviour is configurable.

**The bad news is:** Usually the VPN admin restricts the user ability to change this setting on it client configuration.

Hope this helps