# Working with VNC / RDP and VPN together

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn, vnc, tightvnc

My question here is an exact duplicate of the one posted [here](https://superuser.com/q/189874/34815) except that I am asking this question specific to Nortel VPN Client and RDP (Remote Desktop)

I am connecting to a Virtual Server via [tightvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/). Once I am in the virtual server I connect to my corporate VPN using Nortel VPN Client. (we have to use nortel  and nothing else). Once the virtual server connects to the VPN I lose my current VNC / RDP session.

How can this situtation be rectified ?

Virtual Server OS is: Windows 7
Desktop Machine OS is: Win XP
Nortel VPN Client: V07_01.280

Based on the comments I am editing this question

1. The solution given on other posts do not work as Nortel VPN Client does not seem to create a new network adapter
2. The question I am asking here is different because I am asking it with specific to Nortel VPN Client
3. I am remoting my virtual server using VNC / RDP. I am connecting to the VPN on my virtual server

Comment: And the the solution to your exact duplicate did not work? If you have tried the solution and it still fails please include that in your question otherwise your question will be closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: Also, are you connecting the virtual server to the vpn or your desktop to the vpn?

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide much detail around the Virtual Server you are trying to connect to, but I guess you connect via RDP from a *client PC Machine M* to a *server S* located on a *network N* and while connected to M, you setup a *VPN connection to Network V*. Is that correct?

If yes, the most likely reason why your connection to *Server S* drops is because your VPN client was configured to prevent [Split Tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).

Under this sort of configuration the VPN client modifies the normal IP routes so that **all traffic leaving the client PC must flow through the VPN tunnel** (excluding of course the traffic required to establish the VPN tunnel itself).

As consequence, the session between *Machine M* and *Server S* is not routed via the tunnel to *VPN Network V* and from there redirected to *Server S* on *Network N*.

This will generally cause many issues due to one of the following:

- The traffic routed to the VPN tunnel will suffer NAT before reaching to Network N and as consequence *Server S* will reject packets as Sequence numbers and other TCP session values on *Machine M* don't match those on *Server S*;
- The router on *Network V* doen't know or intentionally block the traffic to *Network N* the connection will simply be dropped.

**The good news is:** This behaviour is configurable.

**The bad news is:** Usually the VPN admin restricts the user ability to change this setting on it client configuration.

Hope this helps